# SPRESENSE $QZQSMセンテンスの受信について

Tags: spresense

QZSSのL1S信号を受信しようとおもっております。

[SPRESENSE GNSS測位情報のNMEA出力方法について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49401/spresense-gnss%E6%B8%AC%E4%BD%8D%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1%E3%81%AEnmea%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)

上記の投稿を参考にしてすすめましたが、NMEAセンテンスにて$QZGSVは受信できましたが、$QZQSMセンテンスをが受信できません。

ATコマンドは下記のように投げております。他にも必要なコマンドがございましたらご教授いただければ幸いです。
@GNS 0x29
@GCD
---- NMEA出力 -----
@GSTP
@AEXT

Answer (score 2):

SPRESENSE SDKのNMEA出力ライブラリは下記のセンテンスのみ対応しているようです。
$xxGGA
$xxGLL
$xxGSA
$xxGSV
$xxGNS
$xxRMC
$xxVTG
$xxZDA

参考リンク
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/developer-tools/api-reference/api-references-spresense-sdk/group__gnss__nmea.html
https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-nuttx/nuttx-developer-guide#_nmea_output

両者で記載内容が微妙に異なっているのがちょっと気になりますが…

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
ご返事が遅くなり、大変申し訳ありません。

お問い合わせのQZSSの$QZQSMによる災忌通報の通知についてですが、
残念ながら現在のファームウェアではまだ対応しておりません。
こちら現在検討を行っており、4月のアップデートにて対応を予定しております。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Answer (score 0):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

QZSSの$QZQSMによる災危通報の通知についてですが、
昨日リリースされましたSDK バージョン 1.2.1にて対応を致しました。
是非こちらのバージョンに更新頂き引き続きご利用いただけますでしょうか。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム